# Create a New Calculated Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know this is going to be easy but I cannot remember how to do it, I have query see below where I want to add a new column called Total Capacity, This is my datediff result * my Capcity. But for the life of me I cannot figure it out. Can you help?

```
SELECT
  Capacity.StartDate
  ,Capacity.EndDate, DATEDIFF(d,Capacity.StartDate
  ,Capacity.EndDate)+1 AS DaysOpen
  ,Capacity.Capacity
  ,Capacity.Site_Skey
FROM
  Capacity
```

the result

```
  StartDate   EndDate       DaysOpen   Capacity TotalCapacity
  01/05/2010  30/09/2010    153        46       7038
```

Comment: What does TotalCapacity represent?

Comment: Days Open * Capacity, in my sample 46 is the daily capacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily add those two columns to your table - as computed, persisted columns. Then you'll have them available for easy selection - they're new column in your table, that you can select like the other columns - and you can even put an index on them, if you need to!

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Capacity]
    ADD DaysOpen AS DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, EndDate) PERSISTED

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Capacity]
    ADD TotalCapacity AS DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, EndDate) * [Capacity] PERSISTED
```

Now you can issue:

```
SELECT
    StartDate, EndDate,
    DaysOpen,
    Capacity,
    TotalCapacity
FROM
    Capacity
```

**Update:** if you want to use the `DATEDIFF+1` approach - use these column specifications:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Capacity]
    ADD DaysOpen AS (DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, EndDate) + 1) PERSISTED

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Capacity]
    ADD TotalCapacity AS (DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, EndDate) + 1) * [Capacity] PERSISTED
```

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't.  Part of normalization is to not store calculated values.

Comment: @DanBracuk: agreed - but part of **denormalization** is to *make it work* and if you need these values frequently, it might be the lesser evil to calculate and (redundantly) store those values for quick access....

Comment: Hi Marc_s

The second part of your solution doesn't calculate correctly, for example when I run it for 46 Capacity for 153 the total should be 7038 but using your solution I am only getting 6992?

Comment: @wafw1971: `DATEDIFF` for those two dates you gave is **152** (and not 153 as you used). So maybe, depending on your definition, you'd need to use `DATEDIFF() + 1` in the specification for the `DaysOpen` and `TotalCapacity` computed columns.

Comment: Hi Marc

I did add the +1 to the first solution and that worked fine its only the second one where I add the +1 after EndDate) and before the * [Capacity] that I get the incorrect results. 

Thanks

Comment: @wafw1971: updated my response with computed column specs that work (at least on my computer :-) )

Comment: Thanks Marc I was missing ) after the +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  Capacity.StartDate
  ,Capacity.EndDate
  ,DATEDIFF(d,Capacity.StartDate ,Capacity.EndDate)+1 AS DaysOpen
  ,Capacity.Capacity
  ,(DATEDIFF(d,Capacity.StartDate ,Capacity.EndDate)+1) * Capacity.Capcity as TotalCapacity
  ,Capacity.Site_Skey
FROM
  Capacity
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
SELECT
  Capacity.StartDate
  ,Capacity.EndDate
  ,DATEDIFF(d, Capacity.StartDate, Capacity.EndDate) + 1 AS DaysOpen
  ,Capacity.Capacity
  ,(DATEDIFF(d, Capacity.StartDate, Capacity.EndDate) + 1) * Capacity.Capacity AS TotalCapacity
FROM
  Capacity
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  Capacity.StartDate
  ,Capacity.EndDate
  ,DATEDIFF(d,Capacity.StartDate
  ,Capacity.EndDate)+1 AS DaysOpen
  ,Capacity.Capacity
  ,Capacity.Site_Skey
  ,(DATEDIFF(d,Capacity.StartDate
  ,Capacity.EndDate)+1 ) * Capacity.Capacity
FROM
  Capacity
```